# Need Help on Creating a ProgressDialog in Android?

Tags: android

Hai dudes, 
      Cany anyone tell me how to Create a ProgressDialog in Android?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the below code if this helps you..

```
     //progress bar

    final ProgressDialog progress_dialog = new ProgressDialog(DialogboxExample.this);
    progress_dialog.setMessage("Loading please wait..");
    progress_dialog.setCancelable(true);

    Button btnprogress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btnprogress.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            progress_dialog.show();
        }
    });


    //progress bar percentage wise

    final ProgressDialog progress_dialog2;
    progress_dialog2 = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progress_dialog2.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    progress_dialog2.setMessage("Loeading..");
    progress_dialog2.incrementProgressBy(10);
    //progress_dialog2.setProgress(100);
    progress_dialog2.setCancelable(true);

    Button btnprogress2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    btnprogress2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        { progress_dialog2.show();}
    });
```

Comment: @Mr.krunal shah: can u pls tell me how to change that loading symbol of daisy wheel to some other symbol

Comment: @Ganesh Sorry but i dont know how to change loading symbol

Comment: @kurnal Shah: With the Help of ur code i got solution & i posted my answer too, i used count down timer to dismiss the Progress Bar after certain time expiration

Answer (score 6):

Come on try to think first! http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog

Comment: @Mr.Warren Faith: Actually i tried this but that code not working for me the code is ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "",
"Loading. Please wait...", true);

Comment: than you should specify your question, tell us what you have programmed and what happens, what kind of error you got... you are a user registered 28 days ago, you asked 20 questions and still don't know how to ask a good specific question... don't forget, the answers will be only as good as the question is...

Comment: @Mr.Warren Faith :It runs eventhough the page is loaded ,similar like a infinite loop

Comment: I guess you never call `dismiss`... thats why it will never disappear... also I stop here, because you simply dont understand how this works... try again with a better question...